# Django Error when running server locally - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django, server, localhost

Getting below error when trying to run server in VS Code for Django.
Command: python manage.py runserver
Error:

```
C:\DjangoServerTest\DjangoServerTest>python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 601, in run_with_reloader
    exit_code = restart_with_reloader()
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 230, in restart_with_reloader
    p = subprocess.run(args, env=new_environ, close_fds=False)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
    process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 121, in create_process
    shlex.split(command),
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shlex.py", line 305, in split
    return list(lex)
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shlex.py", line 295, in __next__
    token = self.get_token()
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shlex.py", line 105, in get_token
    raw = self.read_token()
  File "C:\Users\subhasispanda\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\shlex.py", line 136, in read_token
    nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Can you please help here?

Comment: I would recommend you to follow [this tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django) that explains how to run a Django app with VS Code. Are you following any particular tutorial or simple example? Please include the relevant section of the code from the Django app (i.e. the `manage.py` file).

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue.
What i did is that i went to control panel -> search -> advanced system settings ->environment variables -> Path
then cleared all paths
Uninstalled python, and deleted all the python related files in the "C:\Users{user_name}\AppData\Local\Programs" directory
And then downloaded the latest one and installed again.
Then added the scripts folder and the python folder directory into the PATH.
Then installed pip and then django.
Now its woking perfectly.

In short remove all the versions of python completely and then install it again. Also clear all the unwanted "paths" in the environment variables.....

Answer (score 0):

I spent around 2 hours on the same issue that I was facing.
I could not understand why the error is occurring but I found the solution by simply **uninstalling python and re-installing it**.
In my case I had more than 1 number of python versions installed so I deleted all the 'site-packages' folder too and installed the latest version of python again and it worked.
Let me know if this works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read' in Django, I uninstalled a package called "subprocess.run" with "pip uninstall [package-name]" and that's all. You can run your project